# C++ Compare user input with each line in .txt file

Tags: c++

The task: (somekind of a lotto comparing program) User inputs 7 numbers (from 1 to 39) and those numbers are compared to each line (of 7 numbers) in a text file.

if the user input (7 numbers) matches more than 3 times in any of the lines, it should say at the bottom that it's not ok.

**Example:**
*Text file:*

2,5,8,16,25,27,32

1,4,15,19,22,25,36

7,12,13,27,35,38,39

.
.
.

*User input in the program:*

1,5,16,21,25,32,36

---

*Now the program should display:*

2,5,8,16,25,27,32 matches: 4

1,4,15,19,22,25,36 matches: 3

7,12,13,27,35,38,39 matches: 0

.
.
.

There are more than 3 matches!

---

For now my code is this (but it only checks the first line and displayes the same amount of matches in all lines):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int z=0;
    int rezultati;
while (z!=1) {
    cout<<"Title of the program"<<endl;
     //Odpri txt
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("stevilke.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
      line=rezultati;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";



 //Glavni prog:
  cout<<"Napisi stevilke (1 enter 2 enter 3 enter ...)"<<endl;
  cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g;
  if (a>0 && a<40 && b>0 && b<40 && c>0 && c<40 && d>0 && d<40 && f>0 && f<40 && g>0 && g<40){

      // preveri enake
      string line;
      ifstream myfile ("stevilke.txt");
      while (getline (myfile,line)){
          //računam numom
          const int n = 7 ;
              std::srand( std::time(0) ) ;


              int lottoresults [39] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39} ;

              for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i );
              // numbers entered by the user
              int userinput[n] = { a, b, c, d, e, f, g } ;
              for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i );

              // check for matching numbers
              int cnt_matches = 0 ; // #matches

              for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ) // for each number entered by the user
              {
                  const int user_num = userinput[i] ;

                  // check if the number entered by the user is a winning number
                  // (could use std::find() instead of writing a loop of out own)
                  for( int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j ) // for each winning number
                  {
                      if( user_num == lottoresults[j] ) // is it the same as user_num?
                      {
                          // yes, we got a match
                          ++cnt_matches ;
                          std::cout << a<<"," << b<<"," << c<<","<< d <<","<< e <<","<< f <<","<< g <<".";
                      }
                  }
              }

              std::cout << "Ujemanja : " << cnt_matches << '\n' ; //TUKI !  --- cnt_matches je v vsaki vrsti enak, spremenit da se spreminja za usako vrsto!





          // numom do tu

      cout << line <<'\n';
            }





      //Piši v txt
      /*std::ofstream ofs;
        ofs.open ("stevilke.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

        ofs <<endl;
        ofs <<a<<","<<b<<","<<c<<","<<d<<","<<e<<","<<f<<","<<g;

        ofs.close(); */



cout<<"pritisni 1 za ponovitev programa, karkoli drugega program zapre."<<endl;
  }
  //konc if-a
  else
cout<<"Dej se ne zajebavi no.. vpis prave stevilke"<<endl;
cout<<"Se enkrat zazeni program."<<endl;
system("pause");
}
return 0;
}
```

Sorry for long question, but I'm struggeling with this problem for 3 nights already and I can't solve it...
I'm just a begginer in c++ and I'd really appriciate ANY help you could give me!

Also sorry for my bad english (not native).

If you need any more informations or code or anything, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: You read into the `line`, but then seem to compare user input against `lottoresults` and not against the `line`. That would explain getting the same result for each line...

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get home to my laptop! Thank you for help my friend!

Comment: I tried that, but it still seems not to work :/
Could you try to modify it and post it back, please?

(sorry for double post)

Comment: I still didn't figure this out.. Can someone help please?